# Adjust CSS Borders

Tags: javascript, css

How do I make the red border perfectly overlap the grey border?

Just have this set as of:

`` const StyledSelect = styled(Select)`
border: 1px solid red; ``

The rendered HTML is:

```
<div class="clearfix">
   <div class="Search_search__fYl81 sc-bdVaJa xpdcY">
      <div class="Select dropdown-arrow Select--single is-clearable is-searchable">
         <div class="Select-control">
            <span class="Select-multi-value-wrapper" id="react-select-2--value">
               <div class="Select-placeholder">Search</div>
               <div class="Select-input"><input role="combobox" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="" aria-haspopup="false" aria-activedescendant="react-select-2--value" class="Select-input" value=""></div>
            </span>
            <span class="Select-arrow-zone"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true" style="color: rgb(153, 153, 153);"></i></span>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

[image: border: 1px solid red]

[border: 10px solid red;](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RdBP.png)
[image: border: 10px solid red;]

Comment: give you code which you trying to do.

Comment: Your HTML would be valueable here because it looks like you are targeting the wrong element.

Comment: Edited my original post to provide css and rendered HTML.